# counting input type text fields that are completed via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

**Problem: Tried two different ways to make code count the amount of fields completed; Keeps outputting "0" or "5", which obviously shows that it doesn't work.**

I'm actually fairly new to JavaScript so I don't know if it's something obvious that I'm missing or not. Although I searched and found a couple that were related, they dealt with using jQuery.

HTML PART:

```
        <form id="form1">
            <input type="text" id="choice0" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="choice1" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="choice2" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="choice3" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="choice4" /><br />
        </form>
        <button onClick="choicesCompleted()">Update Wheel</button>
        <button type="reset" form="form1">Restart</button>

        <p>choices filled: <span id="showc"></span></p>
```

JS PART:

```
function choicesCompleted() {
var c = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("choice" + i).value != null) {
        c = c + 1;
    }
}
document.getElementById("showc").innerHTML = c;
}
```

Like I mentioned before, other solutions dealt with jQuery and although it may not be typical, I was just trying to complete this by just using JavaScript. I am trying to get in more practice and some understanding as to why it's not working.

I tried going a different route by pushing a simple value of the text input into an array and then displaying it but it also leads to a dead end. Here is an example of a simple test I tried to run to see if it would even work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>ANSWER: <span id="here"></span></p>

<input type="text" id="line0" />
<button onclick="pleaseWork();">Submit</button>

</body>

<script>
function pleaseWork() {
var array = [];
array.push(document.getelementbyid("line0").value);
document.getelementbyid("here").innerHTML = array[0];
}
</script>
</html>
```

Sorry for the formatting on this one, I was doing it in an online editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for `null` when you should be checking that the value does not equal `''` (the value of an empty input).

Your second example is not working because the method to get an element by its id is `getElementById` and you were using `getelementbyid`.

```js
function choicesCompleted() {
  var c = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("choice" + i).value !== '') {
      c = c + 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("showc").innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="choice0" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="choice1" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="choice2" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="choice3" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="choice4" />
  <br />
</form>
<button onClick="choicesCompleted()">Update Wheel</button>
<button type="reset" form="form1">Restart</button>

<p>choices filled: <span id="showc"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: CODE WORKS! i really appreciate the quick response! do you mind explaining why the bottom one wouldn't work?

Comment: @ccoog Happy to help. Just updated with why the second example does not work.